# Exported kvm kernel functions get undefined warning when compiling a kernel driver that calls them

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kvm

I'm trying to call two exported (maybe) kernel functions from the KVM - `kvm_write_guest` and `kvm_get_segment` but when I compile a kernel driver that will call these two functions I get a warning saying they are undefined.

```
WARNING: "kvm_write_guest" [/home/driver.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "kvm_get_segment" [/home/driver.ko] undefined!
```

When I executed the commands:

```
cat /proc/kallsyms | grep kvm_get_segment
cat /proc/kallsyms | grep kvm_write_guest
```

to check to see if they are exported I get the following:

```
0000000000000000 t kvm_write_guest  [kvm]
0000000000000000 t kvm_get_segment  [kvm]
```

Below are the protocols and includes that I have in the header file that is included in the .c file that calls these functions.  I pulled the prototypes from the kvm_main.c code.

```
#include <linux/kvm.h>
#include <linux/kvm_types.h>
#include <linux/kvm_host.h>
int kvm_write_guest(struct kvm *kvm, gpa_t gpa, const void *data, unsigned long len);
void kvm_get_segment(struct kvm_vcpu *vcpu, struct kvm_segment *var, int seg);
```

When I dig into the `kvm_main.c` source code for `kvm_write_guest` they don't seem to be exported using the following code:

```
EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL(kvm_write_guest);
```

When I dig into the x86.c code for `kvm_get_segment` it isn't exported using that method either.  It doesn't seem that they are in fact exported but I want to make sure I'm not doing something wrong.  I'd like to avoid patching the code and recompiling if I can.  Thank in advance for any help it is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong. If they're not exported with EXPORT_SYMBOL or EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL, you won't be able to call them from a module.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have two different problems.  `kvm_get_segment` is only defined in arch/x86/kvm/x86.c and is not exported.  So another module can't link to it (without patching the source or playing complicated tricks at runtime).

On the other hand, as you point out, `kvm_write-guest` *is* exported, with:

```
EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL(kvm_write_guest);
```

That means only GPL-licensed modules can link to it; you'll need to put

```
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

in your driver to use that symbol.  (And make sure you understand the legal implications of doing that)